# Extract the last 7digit contiguous sequence in a mixed alphanumeric and characters input txt using scripting or regex

Tags: regex, shell

I have my input text file with mixed characters and alphabets and numbers.

My output is 7 continuous digits mixed(basically random 7-digits). I need to extract them using shell or regex. Problem mainly is each time we might have more sets of 7 digits or more than 7 digits togther, Output needed, from the last set of digits that are more than 7 digits, first 7 didgits to be retrieved.

EXAMPLE for INPUTS: 
**"xdscd dv 346 34,r45r 1267890 @#$%hbevc 123456789 bjhbjhb#$%^"** 
(OR)
 **"xcfgvhbj @#$% 23456876 cghd jhsefc4567 12345678 cdvcdfv%^&* 56789"**. So my req is to extract 1234567

Comment: Can you share your current regex and where it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `\d{7}(?!.*\d{7})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhdlpw/1)